# Mysql database import

Tags: mysql

I have a database by the name of `test_db` and exported (`mysqldump test_db > test_db.sql`) that as `test_db.sql` and know I have created a database in the same Mysql server by the name of `test_db_new` and want to import `test_db.sql` dump into `test_db_new` like below command:

```
>mysql test_db_new < test_db.sql
```

My question is: is it affect on `test_db`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because my friend faced such issue and he imported the database but it was overwritten the old database `test_db`.

Comment: @CBroe, please see the answer. why you voted down the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how it was exported and what's in the `test_db.sql`. Look at it, it's just a text file.

Loading it into mysql command can do anything you can do in queries. It may contains just `CREATE TABLE ...` and `INSERT INTO ...` statements, in which case it's safe to use the way you want.

But it may just as well start with `DROP DATABASE test_db; CREATE DATABASE test_db;`.

Without knowing the contents, we can't give you any guarantees.

If you use `mysqldump` without any extra options... we still can't guarantee anything :) The standard options are safe - you won't drop the original database, only the existing tables in the new database. But, even without explicit arguments, some options can be imported from your local configuration file.

You'll have to verify for yourself:

- is your sql script dropping any databases?
- does it run `USE ...;` to switch databases?
- does it refer to tables with the database prefix rather just the table name?

If none of those are happening, you *should* be safe.

Comment: Yes you are right @viraptor, I exported with `mysqldump test_db > test_db.sql` command.

Comment: @GulmuhammadAkbari added some more context for verification

Comment: Thank you @viraptor, I will consider what you mentioned.